# good pratice to save ML model with scaling and other info required for re-use

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm not a good good coder, but try to upgrade my skill and use good way for structure and pratice.

I'm working on ML an use Keras. I try t find the best way to save my results.
I got a model, scale parameter for x and y sims data, original features and Y.
What is the best pratice to save all that info data? 
It is possible or good idea to save my model with my scale param togetter?
I read csv and turn it to pandas DataFrame, it is better to save DataFrame to work directly with it next time or continu to read csv?

Thank a lot for your suggestion an patience for a noob
PS: sorry for my poor english, Im working on it too

Comment: For what exactly are you storing the data? Usually you just save your trained model and the configuration of prepocessing, scaling is not really neccecary in neural networks

Comment: to run again the same model rapidly. As I use scalling on my trainning data, I need this param to sim new datas.

Comment: I want to fine tune my model with new data too, so I need to reload my model in exact same config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using keras, not only sci-kit learn, so I would build a pipeline and save both separately.

```
from keras.models import load_model
from sklearn.externals import joblib

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('estimator', KerasClassifier(build_model))
])

pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
# save keras model
pipeline.named_steps['estimator'].model.save('keras_model.h5')

# save pipeline
pipeline.named_steps['estimator'].model = None
joblib.dump(pipeline, 'sklearn_pipeline.pkl')

# deserialize
pipeline = joblib.load('sklearn_pipeline.pkl')

# add keras model
pipeline.named_steps['estimator'].model = load_model('keras_model.h5')
```

Comment: I realy like this way, Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are trying to save the model for re use. If I understand correctly this can help.

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib

joblib.dump(clf, 'filename.pkl') 

clf = joblib.load('filename.pkl')
```

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html#persistence-example

Comment: if I do:      scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1)), scaler.fit_transform(valuesX) your command clf = joblib.load('filename.pkl') will restore my "scaler" ?

Comment: Yes, it will restore the scaler.